# Keep user session authenticated in ionic app after logging in

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, passport.js

I have a web application and all its get and post requests in back-end is written in nodejs, where after the user logs in passport stores the session and whenever now users makes request I can check if user is logged in or not using `req.isAuthenticated()`,

**NOW**  I am developing application for android platform as well using ionic framework,

the problem I am facing is after user logs in successfully, and try to gets the access his profile page, where `isLoggedIn()` check is done where it fails again as the session is not saved, and redirects me back to login page.

MY question is how can I save the session in cookie in my ionic app, so that I can access my api's, I know I can use `passport-jwt` but then I will have to change all the login starategies, Is there any other way like by sending the jwt token and I can check for it in my `isLoggein()` function.

> What changes should I make in back-end to save my logged in user session.